# jQuery selector is not selecting the DOM element with a long length id

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have created a span with id="photo_e8c34d96-dea7-4e60-9dcf-e9b7efaf856e.jpg"
like:

```
<span id="photo_e8c34d96-dea7-4e60-9dcf-e9b7efaf856e.jpg">Some Text</span>
```

Now when I used to access it with jQuery, it's not accessing it:

```
$("#photo_e8c34d96-dea7-4e60-9dcf-e9b7efaf856e.jpg")
```

It selects an undefined object. How can I access it ?

Comment: Remove the .jpg - much simpler than escaping the dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use . the answer is using @\\ as explained above

```
$("#photo_e8c34d96-dea7-4e60-9dcf-e9b7efaf856e\\.jpg");
```

as per your another question of changing . to \ when using id 
you can try this

```
var tempid = "#photo_e8c34d96-dea7-4e60-9dcf-e9b7efaf856e.jpg".split(".");
var id = tempid[0] + "\\" + tempid[1];
```

Comment: How can I dynamically add "\" before "." after taking this id attribute value to var ?

Answer (score 3):

need to escape `.` in the id using `\.` because otherwise it will consider the part after `.` as a class selector

So your selector is looking for an element with id `photo_e8c34d96-dea7-4e60-9dcf-e9b7efaf856e` and class `jpg`

Again `\` is the string escape character in JavaScript, so in the string you need to escape `\` with `\\` to get a string `\.`

```
$("#photo_e8c34d96-dea7-4e60-9dcf-e9b7efaf856e\\.jpg")
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/JvHc4/)

Answer (score 3):

escape the `.` operator

```
 $("#photo_e8c34d96-dea7-4e60-9dcf-e9b7efaf856e\\.jpg")
```

`.` is a class selector in jquery.. so you have to escape that with `\`.

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

as of why `\\`.. to get the string as `\.` we need to escape it with  `\`.the jquery doc itself has a link posted explaining the set of rules which is very helpful and recommend you to go through it...

[jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 0):

for special(.,#,+,-,*,/ and many more) we use character  "\" so use

`$("#photo_e8c34d96-dea7-4e60-9dcf-e9b7efaf856e\\.jpg")` like this way